# Bringing my video game on an international flight

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, electronic-items, california

I read the questions on this website about video games but I'm still confused, it is my first time dealing with this kind of stuff. I live in Brazil and I'm planning to fly to California - Los angeles. I would like to bring my two video games (Playstation 2) + accessories with me. Is it allowed? I've searched on the internet and talked to people that I know but the answers are mixed. I bought them from someone else and there is no documentation.

Comment: I don't see why not, if you're also going to bring them back to Brazil with you - people bring PSPs on flights all the time, and bringing a couple of disks and accessories isn't really much more than bringing a handheld console.

Comment: Glad to know, thank you

Comment: bringing 2 old game consoles with you might however raise some eyebrows at customs, people thinking you've got drugs hidden in them for example.

Comment: I guess if someone who works there gets concerned about it at the day I might be able to open it and show that there is nothing to hide

Answer (score 3):

That's no problem at all.

Generally, you can bring with you whatever you want unless it's illegal or you are planning on selling or leaving it in the guest country.

For some more esoteric items you may need something like a "carnet" for temporary importation, but a Playstation 2 is clearly NOT in that category.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One problem you might run into is region locking of the games - Sony region locks games based on their display system, ie NTSC, NTSC-J, PAL.

Brazil seems to be PAL-M based, while the US is NTSC based.

Your games will get past security and customs just fine, but they might not play on a unmodified US Playstation.

Comment: I think he means the hardware. He'd not be able to play games bought in the US on it but he'd be able to bring games he took with him to the US just fine. PAL - NTSC would be a bigger problem, not sure if the Sony hardware supports both.

Comment: @jwenting i definitely do not get the impression that they are talking about actual consoles.

Comment: Jwenting is right but Moo's information still pretty interesting

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Allan. I interpreted this "two video games (Playstation 2) + accessories" as "two video games, Playstation 2, and accessories." Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @travelgasm I think you just added one more item but your answer is just fine. To be honest I'm kind of confused now by your question haha

Comment: @Allan Apologies, think I misread this thread. You are saying that jwenting's interpretation is correct, so I also was correct that you are referring to the console, games, and accessories and not just games and accessories. This is an oxford comma kind of situation; think I got it now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can bring a Playstation 2 and a couple of games, accessories, etc, into the US.

So it will not get damaged in transit, it would be best to pack it in your carry-on bag (which [TSA explicitly allows](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/full-sized-video-game-consoles)), you will just need to place it in a separate bin for screening at security check points.